# Is there a tool that performs automatic recognition of buildings?

Tags: remote-sensing, feature-extraction, image-analysis

I'm wondering if there is a tool, which

1. takes a satellite map of a region,
2. detects typical buildings and
3. allows the user to review its result (check, whether the tool correctly identified the buildings).

By "typical buildings" I mean the following: In some regions there are buildings, which look very similar from above.

For example, single-family houses have roofs, which look nearly identical (see red ellipse in the picture below).

[image: Single-family houses]

Apartment houses also have a distinct shape.

[image: Apartment houses]

So, theoretically it should be possible to identify houses and apartment buildings automatically (with human checking the results).

Is there a tool which allows this?

**Update 1 (20.11.2013 10:47):** Are there any LIDAR images for Russia, which are freely available or can be purchased at low cost?

Answer (score 15):

As Chad Cooper mentioned, what you want to perform is called **[Object-Based Image Analysis](http://wiki.landscapetoolbox.org/doku.php/remote_sensing_methods%3aobject-based_classification)** (OBIA).  It's a fairly complex process which segments and then classifies an image.  There are many programs out there which will perform this for you.  However, you will require high-resolution, multi-spectral imagery.  Incorporating LiDAR will probably help you out too, if you have access to it.  I don't think you'll have too much luck using the Bing imagery you show in your question.  But, I've never tried it.  Bing imagery has been processed to look good as a background and is presented as RGB and doesn't contain the Infrared bands which are useful at picking out rooftops.

There are [**entire textbooks**](http://www.springer.com/earth+sciences+and+geography/geographical+information+systems/book/978-3-540-77057-2) written on the subject of OBIA.  And plenty of journal articles written as well such as [**this one**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0924271609000884), [**this one**](http://www.crcsi.com.au/getattachment/bf39930f-8e39-4eb1-8fac-f95153dd75bb/.aspx), and [**this one**](http://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/3/6/1188).

As far as software goes, I'd look at [**eCognition**](http://www.ecognition.com/).  I haven't used it for a while, but a few years ago it was the industry leader in OBIA.

If you're looking for free solutions, apparently, [**Orfeo Toolbox**](http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/otb/) can perform OBIA - see [**here**](http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/SoftwareGuide/SoftwareGuidech20.html).  You might also want to look at **[SAGA-GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html)** and **[GRASS GIS](http://grass.osgeo.org/)**.  I'm sure you'll find something useful.

Answer (score 2):

NY Public Library did this for scanned maps.  Their code is open-source.  http://www.gislounge.com/automating-extracting-gis-data-scanned-maps/

Answer (score 2):

One of the best OBIA programs available for feature extraction is called [Feature Analyst](http://www.vls-inc.com/feature_analyst.htm) by Overwatch. There is a good promo video on road and building extraction [here](http://www.vls-inc.com/videos/road_building_toolkit.htm).  The software is available as an extension for ArcGIS and Erdas Imagine.  Unfortunately, this is not opensource software.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Our latest research on building detection (identification and footprints) has been integrated into Picterra's platform **https://app.picterra.ch**

Here's a screenshot of one output:
[image]

Have a look at it!